Cairo error: Member is not visible in this context
I'm facing an error in the following function:
fn createRequest(ref self: ContractState, description: ByteArray, value: usize, recipient: ContractAddress) {
  let newRequest = Request { description, value, recipient, isComplete: false, yesVotes: 0, voters: Default::default() };
  self.requests.append(newRequest);
}


None of the properties of my Struct are being recognized by the compiler.
The link for the complete code is here: https://github.com/MullerEsposito/cairo-crowdfunding/tree/muller

The problem was in the lack of access modifiers in my struct, it was that way:
#[derive(Drop, Serde, Store)]
pub struct Request {
    description: ByteArray,
    value: usize,
    recipient: ContractAddress,
    isComplete: bool,
    yesVotes: usize,
    voters: List<bool>
}

The struct was marked as public but the properties also need to be marked as public like this:
#[derive(Drop, Serde, Store)]
pub struct Request {
    pub description: ByteArray,
    pub value: usize,
    pub recipient: ContractAddress,
    pub isComplete: bool,
    pub yesVotes: usize,
    pub voters: List<bool>
}

